# pattern.match with regex not working

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

def test(stest):
    pattern = re.compile(r'/product\/(.*?)/i')

    result = pattern.match(stest)
    if result:
       print result.group()
    else:
       print "Doesn't match"

test('product/WKSGGPC104/GGPC-The-Paladin')
```

When I run the coding as the above, I will get "Doesn't match" for the result instead of 'product/'.

Could someone help me out? I have tested regular expression by using the online tool, it shows fine and matches the string that I am going to test.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: if the strings always start with the prefix 'product' then just leave out the beginning / from the regex expression and it should work fine else if its somewhere in the string but not the beginning always, use re.search() since it scans the entire string for matching substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues with your code.
First, there was no `/` in the beginning, second, you provide the modifiers **after** the call:

```
import re

def test(stest):
    pattern = re.compile(r'product/([^/]+)'. re.IGNORECASE)

    result = pattern.match(stest)
    if result:
       print(result.group())
    else:
       print("Doesn't match")

test('product/WKSGGPC104/GGPC-The-Paladin')
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](http://ideone.com/TBgQMN).

Comment: Thank you,mate. It really helps me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using string literals but still escaping the \ in your string.